# How do I remove only few url parameters in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, url-parameters, urlvariables

I am trying to develop an application using zend framework (v 1.11). Am totally new to this framework.

I have a URL like this.

`http://xyz.local/client/feedback/index/username/abc/page/2`

The above link points to `client` module, `feedback` controller's `index` action.

**url parameter `username` along with a valid value is necessary for every request.**

On this page I have paginated all the feedbacks. My probem is that when I navigate away from the `index` action to some other action in same or different controller the parameter name `/page/2` still remains in the url.

For suppose if I navigate to `new` action of same controller then the new URL appears like this

`http://xyz.local/client/feedback/new/username/newClient/page/2`

whereas it should have been like this

`http://xyz.local/client/feedback/new/username/newClient`

Using the `$this->url(array('module' => 'client', 'controller' => 'feedback', 'action' => 'new'), null, true)` resets all the parameters including the username, which I do not want.

What's the standard Zend's way of doing this.

Comment: You could pass the username to the view and add it to the url's parameters: `$this->url(array('module' => 'client', 'controller' => 'feedback', 'action' => 'new', 'username' => $username), null, true)` or you just set the page-parameter to `null` and omit the final argument when calling the URL-ViewHelper. I think the former is the cleaner way...

Comment: cool, that worked (former approach).. thanks. :)

Can you please post that reply as an answer to this question.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the username to the view and add it to the url's parameters in the URL-ViewHelper:

```
$this->url(array('module' => 'client', 'controller' => 'feedback', 'action' => 'new', 'username' => $username), null, true)
```